# Parse XML recursively in groovy / java

Tags: java, xml, groovy, xml-parsing

I have the following .XML file:

```
<testItems>
<children>
    <testItem name=TestSuite1>
        <children>
            <testItem name=test1>
            </testItem>
            <testItem name=test2>
            </testItem>
            <testItem name=test3>
            </testItem>
        </children>
    </testItem>
    <testItem name=TestSuite2>
        <children>
            <testItem name=test3>
            </testItem>
            <testItem name=test4>
            </testItem>
            <testItem name=test5>
            </testItem>
        </children>
    </testItem>
</children>
```

I want to implement java / groovy recursive algorithm that will visit each  node, no matter the depth (in the example the maximum depth is 2, but it can vary)

So far I have:

```
root.testItems.children.testItem.each{testItem ->
...rest of code...
}
```

which will visit TestSuite1 and TestSuite2, but I want it to visit all nodes recursively.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code of your attempt writing the recursive function and explain in detail where you are stuck. We won't write the whole code for you but we can help you on your specific problems with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def root = new XmlParser().parseText(...)
root.depthFirst().each{e->
    //do something with each element
}
```